# Can you set up mirroring for sql server reporting services?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs

I have mirroring set up for our SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard database server.

Questions

- How do I ensure high availability for reporting services if the server goes down?
- Is there a kind of mirroring available for that as well?

Answer (score 5):

Mirroring is for individual database.  For reporting services, you can user web server farms (AKA scale out deployment).  It will allow multiple servers in a cluster.  You will need SQL Server Enterprise Edition for this feature, though, as well as a load balancer (Windows has this or NW hardware like BigIP, etc.).  See here for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156453.aspx